# Magento2 - include possible tier price in getProductPrice() product list

Tags: magento2, price, product-list, tierprice, bundle

Our customer would like to display lowest possible price in product list pages. All visible products in website are **bundle** products

This is the function which displays the price

**Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct**

```
public function getProductPrice(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product)
{
    $priceRender = $this->getPriceRender();

    $price = '';
    if ($priceRender) {
        $price = $priceRender->render(
            \Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Price\FinalPrice::PRICE_CODE,
            $product,
            [
                'include_container' => true,
                'display_minimal_price' => true,
                'zone' => \Magento\Framework\Pricing\Render::ZONE_ITEM_LIST,
                'list_category_page' => true
            ]
        );
    }

    return $price;
}
```

The fast try (changing **\Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Price\FinalPrice::PRICE_CODE** to **\Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Price\TierPrice::PRICE_CODE**) obviously doesn't work, as TierPrice should return an array or some complex data and not a price amount

How to achieve this? Any tips?

**update**

Missed to comment that products in catalog are bundle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 'display_minimal_price' => true
```

Already forces the lowest price to be displayed in your list (as a link), you don't have to change the price code, if tierprice is the lowest possible price.

Example:

[image]

---

If you only want the minimal price to be displayed in your list, you
have to create a new Magento\Catalog\templates\product\price\final_price.phtml in your custom theme and only display the final_price if

`!$block->hasSpecialPrice())` 
and `!$block->showMinimalPrice()`

---

**Edit:** possible solution for bundled products/ just an idea, no time at the moment to check it but maybe it helps you

1. Define a new custom price renderer in your di.xml, so you will only change the behavior in list and don't change bundle product pricing core function

   ```
   <virtualType name="Magento\Bundle\Pricing\Price\Pool" type="Magento\Framework\Pricing\Price\Pool">
   <arguments>
       <argument name="prices" xsi:type="array">
           <item name="bundle_lowest_price" xsi:type="string">Company\CustomPrices\Pricing\Price\BundleLowestPrice</item>
       </argument>
   </arguments>
   ```
2. Define render template for your price renderer in catalog_product_prices.xml

   > `<referenceBlock name="render.product.prices">
   >       <arguments>
   >           <argument name="bundle" xsi:type="array">
   >               <item name="prices" xsi:type="array">
   >                   <item name="bundle_lowest_price" xsi:type="array">
   >                       <item name="render_template" xsi:type="string">Company_CustomerPrices::bundle_lowest_price.phtml</item>
   >                   </item>
   >               </item>
   >           </argument>
   >       </arguments>
   >   </referenceBlock>` >
3. In your BundleLowestPrice.php get the final price  for each bundle option (as simpleproduct) and compare them, return the lowest possible price to your bundle/final_price.phtml

4.final_price.phtml:

```
 $bundleLowestPriceModel= $block->getPriceType('bundle_lowest_price');
 $lowestPrice = $bundleLowestPriceModel->getLowestPrice();
 ...........
 if ($lowestPrice < $minimalPrice < $minimalRegularPrice)
 .... output lowestPrice
```

Comment: I missed one important thing in the question... in this project the visible products are bundle products. I have tried what you say, but the printed prices are not the cheapest selection in bundle, they are kindly lower

Comment: edited my first answer

Comment: Ok I'll work that approach. For me, after your effort, is enough to give you the points. Thanks!